# Cron to tar files by creation date

Tags: unix, cron, tar

I need to create a cron job that will `tar` all images created within the last `X` days.
I use cron jobs on my websites by setting them up in `CPanel`, but I'm not an experienced script writer when it comes to unix stuff. Any help will be appreciated.

This is my cron job:

```
0 4 * * 1 tar pzvcf /home/xxxxxx/public_html/backups/images_backup.tar /home/xxxxxx/public_html/images/products
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use find to locate all the images and feed them to tar.

Something like this should give you file created in the last 2 days (the -2 means < 2*24 hrs)

```
find <path> -ctime -2 -print
```

Something like this probably does the whole job:

```
find <path> -ctime -<within_days> -print | tar cf <output.tar> -T -

You need to specify:
  <path>        (where to search for images)
  <output.tar>  (output file name)
  <within_days> (add files < this many days old)
```

`tar cf <file>` creates a tarball, `tar af <file>` appends to an existing tarball

The `-T -` tells tar to read the list of commands from stdin.

The find command echos the list of matching files to stdout.

The `|` joins the stdout of the find to the stdin of the tar: so tar should add all the file found by the find.

Comment: Will the cron be able to add files to an existing tar?

Comment: Use tar avf instead of cvf to append (c=create, a=append) - you can probably leave the v out too (that just means verbose - not all  that useful in a cron job)

Comment: You'll probably want to restrict `find` to listing regular files only.  If you pass a directory name to `tar`, it will recursively archive the entire directory contents.  Use: `find <path> -type f ...`

Comment: If your filenames may have spaces or other shell metacharacters, you'll need to use the `-print0` argument to `find` instead of `-print`, and then you'll need to include the `--null` option to `tar`.

Comment: Where should I add the --null option in the tar command? And could you please explain what it does?

Answer (score 0):

U can use the following command

```
tar -cvzf outputfilename.tar ` find . -name '*' -mtime -2 -print`
```

In find command
. -> directory to search
* -> file pattern
-2 -> represent no of days

in your case

```
0 4 * * 1 tar -cvz /home/xxxxxx/public_html/backups/outputfilename.tar ` find /home/xxxxxx/public_html/images/products -name '*' -mtime -2 -print`
```

Comment: Could I use find . -name 'l_*.jpg' to tar only the files with that pattern?

Comment: If the list of files is large (thousands) you might get a `command line too long` error using this technique. Also, it's best to restrict `find` to not list directories.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replay. Hope u find it out by testing, U can use the same to find for the pattern. In case of large number of files u can redirect the response to a dummy file (using ">> log filename") .